# How to Split Multiple Strings/Lines into Two Variables

Tags: powershell, variables, powershell-5.1

I am attempting to setup a script where it looks inside a file, retrieves the user description, the username, and the date/time that each of the users logged out. From there I would like to export the information into a .csv file. I was able to successfully retrieve the user description & username cleanly, but I am trying to retrieve the date/time so that it can easily be reviewed as well. To do this, I would like to split the value(s) of the date/time so that one variable is just the dates and the other variable is just the times. From there, I should be able to easily export the information to a csv file in 4 columns (user description, username, logout date, & logout time).

Here is the part of the script I'm having an issue with:

```
#Create Variable for User Description & User ID & Last Logout
[xml]$UserInfoPath = gc $AccountListPath
$UserDescString = $UserInfoPath.AccountList.UserAccount.description
$UserInfoString = $UserInfoPath.AccountList.UserAccount.UserInfo.username
$UserLogoutString = $UserInfoPath.AccountList.UserAccount.UserInfo.LastLogout
$UserLogoutDate,$UserLogoutTime = $UserLogoutString.split("T")
```

This is the output of the $UserLogoutString variable:

[image]

I would like to use the 'T' to split the string on each of the lines so that the $UserLogoutDate variable displays this:

```
2022-11-22
2023-02-01
2022-11-22
2022-12-15
2022-12-02
```

I would like to us the 'T' to split the string on each of the lines so that the $UserLogoutDate variable displays this:

```
11:06:34.311-06:00
11:09:30.903-06:00
11:06:34.311-06:00
13:15:17.003-06:00
16:10:03.179-06:00
```

The variables above, however, are not displaying the way I want them to. I am currently seeing this output:

[image]

Comment: Is `$UserLogoutString` really a string? can you show us the output from `$UserLogoutString.GetType()` ?

Comment: Good catch. It turns out that the type is an array. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear if `$UserLogoutString` is actually a string or already an array.

Assuming this is an array, `-split '\r?\n'` wouldn't be needed in code below.

```
$result = $UserLogoutString -split '\r?\n' | ForEach-Object {
    $date, $time = $_.Split('T')
    @{ $date = $time }
}

$($result.Keys)   # has all the dates
$($result.Values) # has all the times
```

The following would result in an array of [hash tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables?view=powershell-7.2), then via [member access enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_member-access_enumeration?view=powershell-7.2) we can reference all `.Keys` and `.Values` in the array.